# Docker bound mount - can not see changes on browser

Tags: docker, jekyll

I'm using docker-toolbox on windows home.
I was able to run a jekyll-serve web server image to see the default page on browser, but when I try to edit file on VS Code, I can not see the changes after refreshing the browser.

**Any idea why I can not see the changes after refresh?**

---

### Step to reproduce:

First I've git cloned this [repository](https://github.com/BretFisher/udemy-docker-mastery/tree/master/bindmount-sample-1) into my `c:/Users/shaharshokrani/udemy-docker-mastery/bind-mount-sample1` (I'm able to see the files with `ls` on 'cmder' console).

Then I was able to run this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/bretfisher/jekyll-serve) with:

`docker run -v //c/users/shaharshokrani/udemy-docker-mastery/bindmount-sample-1:/site bretfisher/jekyll new .`

`docker container run -p 80:4000 --name myjekyll -v //c/users/shaharshokrani/udemy-docker-mastery/bindmount-sample-1:/site bretfisher/jekyll-serve`

And I'm able to see the default welcome page on `http://192.168.99.100/`.

I've tried to edit and save using VS Code this `2017-03-05-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown` but I can not see the changes after refreshing the browser.

---

I also checked the VM for shared network - it shows `c:/users/`.

Even the `Mounts` on inspect looks good:

```
"Mounts": [
    {
        "Type": "bind",
        "Source": "/c/users/shaharshokrani/udemy-docker-mastery/bindmount-sample-1",
        "Destination": "/site",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],
```

And the image [dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/bretfisher/jekyll-serve/dockerfile)'s `CMD` has the `--force_polling` flag.

Both the images (`bretfisher/jekyll-serve`, `bretfisher/jekyll`) are latest.

The `docker container logs -f myjekyll` looks good:

```
Bundle complete! 4 Gemfile dependencies, 28 gems now installed.
Bundled gems are installed into `/usr/local/bundle`
Configuration file: /site/_config.yml
            Source: /site
       Destination: /site/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 1.031 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/site'
    Server address: http://0.0.0.0:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

---

Docker version:

```
Client:
 Version:       18.03.0-ce
 API version:   1.37
 Go version:    go1.9.4
 Git commit:    0520e24302
 Built: Fri Mar 23 08:31:36 2018
 OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
 Experimental:  false
 Orchestrator:  swarm

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:      19.03.3
  API version:  1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.12.10
  Git commit:   a872fc2f86
  Built:        Tue Oct  8 01:01:20 2019
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
 containerd:
  Version:      v1.2.10
  GitCommit:            b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:      1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:            3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:      0.18.0
  GitCommit:            fec3683
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issue identified

Bind mounting actually does not work for docker toolbox:

> file change events in mounted folders of host are not propagated to
>   container by Docker for Windows

### Solution

This script is intended to be the answer to this issue: [docker-windows-volume-watcher](https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher).

---

### Side note

This is a common issue with data manipulated outside of your container.

For jekyll, in particular, even the solution described in the issue below does not work for windows-based systems.

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-watch/issues/17

In short you need to execute jekyll with the `--force_polling` flag (**Does not work with Windows Hosts**). You can find it in the jekyll docs here

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/

---

On Linux based systems it works out of the box since the image used in the question `bretfisher/jekyll-serve` already utilizes the `--force_polling` flag.

just ran

```
docker run --rm -it -e JEKYLL_NEW=true -p 8080:4000 -v (pwd):/site bretfisher/jekyll new .
```

to create a new jekyll site and

```
docker run --rm -it -e JEKYLL_NEW=true -p 8080:4000 -v (pwd):/site bretfisher/jekyll-serve
```

to run it mounted to a directory on my machine (linux) and was able to edit a file with changes propagating to jekyll.

Comment: just throwing around a few ideas: have you checked in your container, that the files are updated after you have changed them on your local system? e.g. by `docker exec` in your container? latest version of jekyll? If it is not up to date try to update the image to the latest jekyll version. Anything in the logs of the container?

Comment: worked for me, I've updated the answer, which changes, in particular, are you referring to?

Comment: Hey @clemens-kaserer I've updated the question... 1. when I refreshing the browser can't see any new log entries on `log -follow`, is it normal? 2. not sure how to update the file using `docker exec`, I'll look into it

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher Seems like that is related to Windows with Linux containers only: