# What is wrong with my Gulp Watch task with Docker?

Tags: django, docker, sass, gulp

EDIT: Gulp "Watch" doesn't work on windows with a [mounted volumes](https://forums.docker.com/t/file-system-watch-does-not-work-with-mounted-volumes/12038/3) because no "file change" event is sent. My current solution is to run [Docker Windows Volume Watcher](https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher) on my local machine while I see if I can integrate [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58962674/docker-bound-mount-can-not-see-changes-on-browser/58969398#58969398) into my code.

I'm trying to run a gulp watch task in my dockerfile and gulp isn't catching when my files are getting changed.

Quick Notes:

- This set up works when I use it for my locally hosted wordpress installs
- The file changes reflect in my docker container according to pycharm's docker service
- Running the "styles" gulp task works, it's just the file watching that does not

It's clear to me that there's some sort of disconnect between how gulp watches for changes, and how Docker is letting that happen.

[Github link](https://github.com/austincollinpena/dockerize-blog-two/tree/master/django_project)

**Edit: It looks possible to do what I want, [here's a link to someone doing it slightly differently.](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-boilerplate-sass/blob/master/gulpfile.js)

[gulpfile excerpt](https://github.com/austincollinpena/dockerize-blog-two/blob/master/django_project/gulpfile.babel.js):

```
export const watchForChanges = () => {

  watch('scss-js/scss/**/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
  watch('scss-js/js/**/*.js', scripts);
  watch('scss-js/scss/*.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
  watch('scss-js/js/*.js', scripts);
  // Try absolute path to see if it works
  watch('scss-js/scss/bundle.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
}
...
// Compile SCSS through styles command
export const styles = () => {
    // Want more than one SCSS file? Just turn the below string into an array
  return src('scss-js/scss/bundle.scss')
      // If we're in dev, init sourcemaps. Any plugins below need to be compatible with sourcemaps.
    .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.init()))
      // Throw errors
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
      // In production use auto-prefixer, fix general grid and flex issues.
    .pipe(
      gulpif(
        PRODUCTION,
        postcss([
          autoprefixer({
            grid: true
          }),
          require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
          require("postcss-preset-env")
        ])
      )
    )
    .pipe(gulpif(PRODUCTION, cleanCss({compatibility:'ie8'})))
      // In dev write source maps
    .pipe(gulpif(!PRODUCTION, sourcemaps.write()))
      // TODO: Update this source folder
    .pipe(dest('blog/static/blog/'))
    .pipe(server.stream());
}
...
export const dev = series(parallel(styles, scripts), watchForChanges);
```

Docker-Compose:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8002:8000"
      - "3001:3001"
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./django_project:/django_project
    command: >
      sh -c "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: example1
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
MAINTAINER Austin

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Install node
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install nodejs
RUN apt-get install npm -y

# Replace shell with bash so we can source files
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh

# Update Node
# Install base dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
        apt-transport-https \
        build-essential \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        git \
        libssl-dev \
        wget

ENV NVM_DIR /usr/local/nvm
ENV NODE_VERSION 12.14.0

WORKDIR $NVM_DIR

RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/master/install.sh | bash \
    && . $NVM_DIR/nvm.sh \
    && nvm install $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm alias default $NODE_VERSION \
    && nvm use default

ENV NODE_PATH $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/lib/node_modules
ENV PATH      $NVM_DIR/versions/node/v$NODE_VERSION/bin:$PATH


# What PIP installs need to get done?
COPY django_project/requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r /requirements.txt



# Copy local directory to target new docker directory
RUN mkdir -p /django_project
WORKDIR /django_project
COPY ./django_project /django_project


# Make Postgres Work
EXPOSE 5432/tcp


WORKDIR /django_project

RUN npm install gulp-cli -g
```

What do you think could be going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is you are running on windows, right?

If so take a look at the following answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/58969398/12153397

Below the gist of the linked answer

---

### Issue identified

Bind mounting actually does not work for docker toolbox:

> file change events in mounted folders of host are not propagated to
>   container by Docker for Windows

### Solution

This script is intended to be the answer to this issue: [docker-windows-volume-watcher](https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher).

Comment: This seems like it's exactly what I need. Apologies for the ignorance, but how would I run their solution via a dockerfile? What actually is changed here? "docker run --rm -it -e JEKYLL_NEW=true -p 8080:4000 -v (pwd):/site bretfisher/jekyll-serve                                                  
"

Comment: Edit: Using https://github.com/merofeev/docker-windows-volume-watcher is working for now, although I would like to do it without that if possible.

Comment: Hi Austin, sadly I am not aware of a solution that does not require the docker-windows-volume-watcher. If you find something that works without it, let me know. If the answer is sufficient, please accept it ;)

Comment: Isn't the docker run solution they proposed an alternative to docker windows volume watcher?

Comment: I've updated the both this and the linked answer to make it clearer. `docker run --rm -it -e JEKYLL_NEW=true -p 8080:4000 -v $(pwd):/site bretfisher/jekyll-serve` does not relate to your issue. Only the docker-windows-volume-watcher is the solution to the issue. The rest is additional information.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you!